# passing specific struct field as function parameter

Tags: c

In javascript we can do the following:

```
var obj = {alpha: [1, 2, 3], omega:[1, 2, 3]};

function test(field) {
   return obj[field];
}

test("alpha");
```

Now im trying to achieve the same in c using a typedef struct in c:

```
typedef struct FooBar{
   char alpha[50];
   char beta[50];
} FooBar;

FooBar fooBar;

int getTest(type field) {
    return sizeof(fooBar.field);
}

getTest(alpha);
```

Is it possible to somehow just pass in a field name like shown above?

Comment: This sounds like a solution looking for a problem... why would you need this for? If the caller already knows that you are looking for `alpha`, then the caller might as well just use `sizeof(foobar.alpha)` instead of calling a completely pointless function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do it with a macro:

```
#define getTest(t) sizeof(fooBar.t)

typedef struct FooBar {
  char alpha[50];
  char beta[50];
} FooBar;

FooBar fooBar;


int main()
{
  int alphasize = getTest(alpha);
}
```

But I'm not sure if this fulfills your requirement.

Comment: No way, wow. How come this doesnt work with functions? Pretty awesome trick

Comment: It does fill my requirement. Could you add more info ? Like just why it works here

Comment: It works because macros are not functions. Macro are replaced textually before the actual compilation takes place. Here each time you write `getTest(something)` it's like if you wrote `sizeof(foobar.something)`.

Comment: Oh, hang on but that means its not dynamic right? I mean lets assume the software is running in a loop and well I trigger on runtime the getTest again but with a different value, would it work?

Comment: I assume if on runtime I decided to do getTest(beta) I would still get getTest(alpha) result?

Comment: This is just compile time it seems...damn.

Comment: @Asperger what would the type of the argument to `getTest` be? C is a compiled language, once it is compiled, the strings `alpha`, `beta` are no more present anywhere.

Comment: Do you mean that parameter alpha would be somehow stored in some variable that you can change in runtime?

Comment: I assume the type of the argument is a char? Im not entirely sure. The reason im doing this is because I want to create a function that does the following calculation for me (sizeOf(array) / sizeOf(array[0]) and I dont want write that every time as to assure type safety. Now I know I can do this with normal variables but....

Comment: @Asperger if you don't want to write `(sizeOf(array) / sizeOf(array[0])` you can define a macro `#define countof(array) (sizeOf(array) / sizeOf(array[0])` and have `int foo[100]; int bar = countof(foo);` and now `bar` would be 100.

Comment: Although remember, I need to pass a struct field. At the other hand, I could just pass the entire struct itself and done.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot achieve this straightaway. When array names are passed to a function as argument, it decays to the pointer to the first element of the array, so from inside the called function, you cannot directly get the size of the original array, in general.

However, if your array has a special sentinel value, then it can work, but that is a conditional scenario.

Comment: darn it. Thats so unfortunate. Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 1):

No, the members of structs cannot be referenced as variables. Note that C is a compiled language. At runtime, the information about the identifiers used for members is no longer present.

You would need to use separate functions for each member, such as

```
size_t getAlphaSize(void) {
    return sizeof(fooBar.alpha);
}
```

Also note that `sizeof` returns an unsigned value of type `size_t`, not an `int`.

Comment: Ok so thats the only way huh. Darn, I thought there was a more elegant way : (